# Get id from table in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

In my program I am trying to get the current id from a list in Xamarin application, in order to change the bool equivalent to the Id.

In the application, the user is represented with a list, and a switch associated with each element. The goal is to change a bool in the table from false to true when the switch is toggled.

[[image: Screen[1]]

In my .cs file I update the bool when the switch is toggled (See handle_toggled towards the bottom):

```
        public partial class DefineBuilding : ContentPage
    {
        //string currentDefineDescription;
        //int currentDefineId;

        DefineTable current; 


        private const string Url = "http://localhost:5000/define";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<DefineTable> _define;


        public DefineBuilding(DefineTable defineList)
        {
            if (defineList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

            //BindingContext = defineList;

            //currentDefineId = defineList.defineId; 
            //currentDefineDescription = defineList.defineDescription;
            current = defineList;

            InitializeComponent();

            //defineList = Current_item.BindingContext;
        }


        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DefineTable>>(content);
            _define = new ObservableCollection<DefineTable>(posts);
            defineBuildingItems.ItemsSource = _define;


            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        async void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            //current.defineId = 
            current.defineBool = true; 
            defineDataService defineTable = new defineDataService();
            await defineTable.UpdateData(current);

        }

        async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ChecklistPage());
        }




    }
}
```

However when handling the toggle switch I am not able to get the Id. In my xaml file I am able to get the Id, however I do not know how to apply this Id.

Here is a sample from my Xaml file (See BindingContext ="{Binding defineId}" for the Id):

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label  Text="{Binding defineDescription}" 
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="Current_item"/>

                        </StackLayout>

                            <Switch BindingContext ="{Binding defineId}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                                    Toggled="Handle_Toggled"/>

                        </StackLayout>
```

Any idea on how to get the correct Id in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sender is the object that is firing the event, which in this case is a Switch.  And since you have the id assigned as the Switch's binding context, you should be able to retrieve it by doing the appropriate casts:

```
async void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        var id = (int) ((Switch)sender).BindingContext;

        //current.defineId = 
        current.defineBool = true; 
        defineDataService defineTable = new defineDataService();
        await defineTable.UpdateData(current);

    }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Is it possible to get out other elements from the table as well? At the moment, when the table is updated my other properties turn out to be null.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about how you're building the table.  Generally a ListView is a lot more appropriate for a data bound list.

Comment: My tables are created on a seperate project in the backend. Is it possibles to make queries (maybe linq queries) from the application to the backend project. Or is there any way to perform request to the backend project and do my queries from there?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/